# adding user value in increment order in csv file

Tags: shell, awk

I have an input file

```
Aq 1 1 c
Aq 1 1 c
Aq 1 1 c
Aq 1 1 c
Aq 1 1 c
```

where I want to add a variable that I defined

```
var=`cat value.txt'
echo $var
```

giving me output as `3213`
now by using the following commend I want to add `var` to the 2nd and 3rd columns

```
awk '{FS="\t"}{print "chrM",sum1=$var+1,sum2=$var+1,$1,$2}' input.txt > output.txt
```

but it's not working. My desired output is:

```
Aq 3214 3214 c
Aq 3215 3215 c
Aq 3216 3216 c
Aq 3217 3217 c
Aq 3218 3118 c
```

Comment: Please provide more detail than *"not working"*.

Comment: what is the actual output that you get?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
  awk -v var=<value of your variable> -F'\t' '{print $1,var+$2,var+$3,$4;}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: awk -v var=$var '{OFS="\t "; print $1,($2+var),($3+var),$4}'  input.txt > output.txt

Comment: @kapp, do you realise that your "desired output" and Michael's solution do not match?